# GetComponent using Arrays in Unity C#,How to call GetComponent for an item in an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

BoardManager Class:

```
        public void HighlightTile()
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            foreach (GameObject g in GameBoard) //g is the tile prefab with SpriteInfo attached to it
            {
                Vector2 min = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.min;
                Vector2 max = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.max;
                if (mousePos.x > min.x && mousePos.y > min.y && mousePos.x < max.x && mousePos.y < max.y)
                {
                    g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
                }
            }
        }
```

Sprite Info Class:

```
public Vector2 min;
public Vector2 max;


public Vector2 FindMin
{
    get
    {
        return GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.min;
    }
}

public Vector2 FindMax
{
    get
    {
        return GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.max;
    }
}
```

SpriteInfo of a randomly created tile prefab

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoGgW.png)

Whenever I Debug.Log min and max in the HighlightTile method, it returns 0 for both. However, whenever I Debug it in the SpriteInfo class, it returns the correct number. On the Editor, each Tile Clone that gets created also has the correct info within them, it's just when I call it in Highlight tile it becomes 0. I believe it's something wrong with my min = g.GetComponent().bounds.min & max. g is the tile prefab with SpriteInfo attached to it. How would I get the correct info in my HighlightTile method?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not related to the answer for this but for performance optimization, try to reduce using `GetComponent<T>()`. You can either get all `SpriteInfo` or `SpriteRenderer` components at the `Start()` function of BoardManager class so GetComponent will only be called once. If you really need to use GetComponent inside `HighlightTile()` method, store it to a local variable `SpriteRenderer sprRenderer = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();` then use that to get the min, max, and change the color to Color.red;

Comment: I'll keep that in minds, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void HighlightTile()
    {
        Vector3 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        foreach (SpriteInfo sprite in GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteInfo>())
        {
            SpriteRenderer renderer = sprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            if (renderer.bounds.Contains(mouse))
                renderer.color = Color.red;
        }
    }
```

You could also add a BoxCollider to each sprite and use OnMouseDown

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I tried that, and the tile does not change color. I also tried a Debug but nothing would pop up. However, the bounds and the mouse's coords fall within eachother